# The question is- how to check if a number is a prime number

Tags: java, loops

**Question**

1. You've to check whether a given number is prime or not.
2. Take a number "t" as input representing count of input numbers to be tested.
3. Take a number "n" as input "t" number of times.
4. For each input value of n, print "prime" if the number is prime and "not prime" otherwise.

**Input Format**
A number t
A number n
A number n
.. t number of times

**Output Format**
prime
not prime
not prime
.. t number of times

**Constraints**
1 <= t <= 10000
2 <= n < 10^9

**Sample Input**
5
19
21
33
37
121

**Sample Output**
prime
not prime
not prime
prime
not prime

*What am I doing wrong? The program is takin inputs alright, but the result is varying again and again. The output is right for some inputs but wrong for some other? What am I missing??*

```java
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            boolean flag = true;
            int t = scn.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                int n = scn.nextInt();
                for (int k = 2; k * k <= n; k++) {
                    if (n % k == 0) {
                        System.out.println("not prime");
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag)
                    System.out.println("prime");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Guess your nextInt doesn't take the good value, print the value after the nextInt to be sure the code use the one you think

Comment: If it doesn't work, replace all the nextint by `Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine())` (i'd suggest to use that 100% of time to avoid any problem

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. In order to improve the chances of getting help here I may suggest you a few small things if it's okay with you. First, I'd suggest editing the title for the question so it's short and more objective right to the point for you're trying to achieve, like 'How do I find if a number is prime' or something like this.

Comment: Also, when you say the answer is wrong, better to try and be more clear about  what exactly do you mean by that, what do you get specifically.

Comment: @Makoto OP example doesn't contain any `nextLine()` call. Are you sure this duplicate is correct here?

Comment: @Pshemo:  That's *exactly* why the dupe is right - because it *doesn't* clear the line.  The dupe will answer this question.

Comment: @Makoto Are you sure that that is the problem and not the fact that `flag` is never reset?

Comment: I'm reasonably confident.  If the OP has an issue with the dupe closure, they can edit their post to clarify.

Comment: @Makoto I realize that this duplicate is very often correct for most Scanner related problems but I am afraid this may not be the case. Notice that problem description states that "answer is wrong for some inputs". So OP claims it is about *result* not *input* (anyway `nextInt` would work regardless of `nextLine` being called or not). Problem here is that `flag` variable is not reset to true for each `n` and will forever become `false` after first non-primal number preventing primal numbers from printing correct message.

Comment: @TheDracula Move `boolean flag = true;` inside `for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)` loop.

Comment: If someone is wondering why I am not voting to reopen despite not agreeing with duplicate selection it is because question is at level of typographical error which is unique enough to not be able to help anyone in the future so it still is off-topic for this site (and I am not sure if at this time more people will gather to cast their close-votes after question will be reopened).

Comment: If you want help with the question, please give us the input, the output, and the expected output. Right now, if I compiled your program, I couldn't say I debugged it, because I don't know your input.

Comment: When you start checking for a new prime, you don't reset flag to true.

Comment: Nomad and Pshemo, u were right. The problem was with the position of my flag statement boolean flag = true;  It was supposed to be inside for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) loop instead of outside. I corrected it and my code worked fully functionally. @FrancislainyCampos It was my first time here. I didn't know any better. But I heard u now, and I will be more accurate and precise while asking questions in the future.. Thanku everyone who commented for making me understand.

Comment: No worries! It takes a bit of time to get to know the best practices here on this platform but little by little you'll get used to it.